# How can I avoid tox reinstalling dependencies and deleting my break point?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, tox

I'm using tox v2.7 and need to set a pdb break point in a dependency library of the library that I'm actually testing/debugging. However I can't stop tox from reinstalling the library and therefore wiping out any change that I made including the break point.

I could find this flag, but I'm not using it:

```
 -r, --recreate        force recreation of virtual environments
```

How can I tell tox to only install dependency packages if they don't exist at all?

The tox.ini in question: https://github.com/belugame/django-auth-ldap/blob/master/tox.ini

Comment: Instead of using `tox` while you're debugging, just activate the virtualenv yourself (`. .tox/py27/bin/activate`).